# Magento 2 How make title required in xml file

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

Its the part admin grid Add button form. I want to make the title field Required.

```
 <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="title">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
            Title
        </argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">title</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Please refer this link :- https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/magento2-system-configuration-validation-html.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the required class

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
</arguments>
```

For more info:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

I hope it will help you!